# Right Click MainMenu

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Having problems with making so when you use right click on mainmenu or Form1 it works and open the specific submenu with Forest,Sea,Clouds and ignores the Pictures ,Exit Menu.
Here you cans see the MainMenu:

[image]

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, ExtCtrls,
  Menus;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    MenuItem1: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem2: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem3: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem4: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem5: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem6: TMenuItem;
    MenuItem7: TMenuItem;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem5Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem6Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MenuItem7Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Panel1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  close;
end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  close;
end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('jura.jpg');
end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('forest.jpg');
end;

procedure TForm1.MenuItem7Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
       Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('clouds.jpg');
end;

procedure TForm1.Panel1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by adding popupmenu now everything works.